# fabric.js - kitchensink - refresh object controls when selecting object

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Pull up the kitchensink. Select the left i-text object "lorem ipsum" and hit the Object tab:
http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink

You'll notice that the "Text specific controls" reflect the contents of the i-text object. Now click on the canvas background (thus un-selecting the object) and finally click on the right "foo bar" i-text object. The text controls again reflect the contents of the i-text object.

So far so good.

What I don't understand is why the controls don't update when you click on the other i-text object without first clicking on the canvas background. Unless you click out of an i-text object the controls seem to remain locked onto the first object. In fact, you can enter some text into the textarea and then select the other i-text object it replaces the entire contents.

How would one clear out the previous selection in the text controls when toggling between i-text objects?

Thanks!!

Comment: found the following which helps but not 100% what I am looking for:

canvas.on('selection:updated', function(e) {
 canvas.discardActiveObject();
});

Comment: IIRC, kitchensink is written in an ancient version of AngularJS and it binds `fabric.js` API calls to angular.js digest loop with something like `$scope.$apply`. So, I'd try finding those angular bindings and look, what fabric.js functions they are listening to. Just look for event, you're interested in in the controller: http://fabricjs.com/js/kitchensink/controller.js

Answer (score 1):

Kitchensink is written in venerable Angular.js 1.2.

So, if you click on your `text specific controls` DOM element in Chrome Developer Tools, you'll see that its html code is: `<div id="text-wrapper" ng-show="getText()">`.

Let's find this `getText()` function in  http://fabricjs.com/js/kitchensink/controller.js. Turns out, it makes angular.js digest loop listen to fabric.js API call (lines 108-113):

```
$scope.getText = function() {
  return getActiveProp('text');
};
$scope.setText = function(value) {
  setActiveProp('text', value);
};
```

So, to refresh text in the text specific controls, apparently, you need to invoke Fabric's `setActiveProp('text', value)` upon switch to other text.

The content of text area in `text-specific-controls` is using `bind-value-to="text"` directive from http://fabricjs.com/js/kitchensink/app_config.js:

```
kitchensink.directive('bindValueTo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',

    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

      var prop = capitalize($attrs.bindValueTo),
          getter = 'get' + prop,
          setter = 'set' + prop;

      $element.on('change keyup select', function() {
        if ($element[0].type !== 'checkbox') {
          $scope[setter] && $scope[setter](this.value);
        }
      });

      $element.on('click', function() {
        if ($element[0].type === 'checkbox') {
          if ($element[0].checked) {
            $scope[setter] && $scope[setter](true);
          }
          else {
            $scope[setter] && $scope[setter](false);
          }
        }
      })

      $scope.$watch($scope[getter], function(newVal) {
        if ($element[0].type === 'radio') {
          var radioGroup = document.getElementsByName($element[0].name);
          for (var i = 0, len = radioGroup.length; i < len; i++) {
            radioGroup[i].checked = radioGroup[i].value === newVal;
          }
        }
        else if ($element[0].type === 'checkbox') {
          $element[0].checked = newVal;
        }
        else {
          $element.val(newVal);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

That directive just watches getter and setter of binded attribute (in our case binded attribute is text, so it watches `getText()`/`setText()` and reflects any changes in UI.